# Difficulty dealing with a bizarre sine function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> $y =x + 2x^2 sin(\frac1x)$ has slope $1$ at $x = 0$. But show that $y$
>   is not increasing on an interval around $x = 0$, by finding points
>   where $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 - 2cos(\frac1x) + 4xsin(\frac1x)$ is
>   negative.

This question puzzles me from the start. $y$ is not defined for $x = 0$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is oscillating infinitely at $x = 0$ instead of staying at $1$. After some trial and error, I managed to find a point where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is negative: $x = \frac4{7\pi}$. But finding all the points where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is negative seems very difficult as there may be infinitely many points. How should I proceed?

Comment: @Qwerty Is $\frac10$ not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that

> $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta> $ such that $2x^2\sin(1/x)<\epsilon$

Hence you can approximate $y=x+2x^2\sin(1/x)$ by $y=x$ for regions near zero like [this.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tjmm347mi9)

[image: $y=x+2x^2\sin(1/x)$]
Hence the first part.

However at the same time check that since the function has an oscilating interval, ou can find a decreasing interval near to zero!

Comment: Can we choose $\delta = \sqrt{\frac\epsilon2}$?

Comment: @W.Zhu As far as this problem is concerned , absolutey yes!. You get my point right? I mean what I am trying to establish in my answer?

Comment: Yes, but we have not specified the points where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is negative, as instructed in the question. Nevertheless, we have somehow proved that such points exist, and this indirectly answers the question.